# how to put the result select of a PDO query in a php variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

in my project I'm using as the PDO connector to access my mysql database.

```
$conexao = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

I am needing filter to get the name of the registered users table usuarios. And for that I'm start a session_start () and ordering him to put the mail in the query.

I'm doing something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'configuracao.php';
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$sql = "SELECT nome from usuarios where email_usuario ='$email'";
$stmt = $conexao -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute();
$nome = $stmt -> fetch();
echo $nome;
?>
```

but I do not know which method takes the result of select ...
the fetch() is not working.

Comment: Explain _fetch() is not working_

Comment: if I access the file.php echo does not print anything.

Comment: Just because you're using PDO, doesn't mean that you're still not open to SQL injection. Use `where email_usuario =:email` then `$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);`

Comment: This is the third or fourth question you've asked on this topic today. You're wasting a lot of time picking your way painfully through what should be a fairly straightforward task. Find a good tutorial and read the reference manuals.

Answer (score 0):

[Fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns an array.

Try:

```
echo $nome['nome'];
```

or

```
echo $nome[0];
```

---

If not specified, you are by default, calling `fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)`.

From the manual:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

print("PDO::FETCH_BOTH: ");
print("Return next row as an array indexed by both column name and number\n");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
print_r($result);
print("\n");
```

Output:

```
PDO::FETCH_BOTH: Return next row as an array indexed by both column name and number
Array
(
    [NAME] => banana
    [0] => banana
    [COLOUR] => yellow
    [1] => yellow
)
```

Comment: did not work I added the bindValue and tested with the array and did not work. 
Here the code: 

<?php
session_start();
require_once 'configuracao.php';
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$sql = "SELECT nome from usuarios where email_usuario =:email";
$stmt = $conexao -> prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt -> execute();
$nome = $stmt -> fetch();
echo $nome['nome'];
?>

Comment: not appear any error and not print anything.
I tested the database connection and it's working normally

Comment: @LucasAraújo Well it's hard to say. The code looks ok to me. I would start by doing at least these 4 things: (1) Confirm that `$email` is correct. (2) Confirm that your query is correct, and that it does return a result, by running it in PhpMyAdmin. (3) call `print_r($nome)` instead of `echo`. (4) Use **[PDO Exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)** to get the PDO error.